# Polymer platinum-push-messaging element

Tags: javascript, push-notification, polymer

I'm trying to figure it out how to use the polymer `<platinum-push-messaging>` element, but without luck. In the documentation for the element it says that you need to register your "gcm_sender_id" and then define the element itself, like this:

```
<platinum-push-messaging
   title="Application updated"
   message="The application was updated in the background"
   icon-url="icon.png"
   click-url="notification.html">
</platinum-push-messaging>
```

In order to test it there is a method called `testPush(message)` but it always returns me the following error:

> platinum-push-messaging.html:437 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'active' of undefined(…)

I don't know if I'm forgetting something, and the [Cat Push Notifications project](https://github.com/notwaldorf/caturday-post) doesn't help at all, i couldn't get it working...

Can anyone point me to the right direction??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `platinum-push-messaging` element can be used to subscribe to push notifications using a `gcm_sender_id` (GCM stands for [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)).

If you're hosting your project on Firebase, you can find your `gcm_sender_id` in the [Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) of your project > Project settings > Cloud Messaging.

Otherwise you can create a Project in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com) and find the ID in the settings (Project Number).

**Note:** Due to the Requirements section in the [Docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/platinum-push-messaging), push messaging is currently only available in Google Chrome.

But let's do a step by step demo (Works for MAC and UNIX - thats what the offical demo supports):

1. Create a new folder and open a Terminal inside it
2. Run `bower init` (for the `bower.json`)
3. Run `bower install PolymerElements/paper-elements` (elements used by the offical demo we will use)
4. Run `bower install PolymerElements/platinum-push-messaging` (you'll get the `bower_components` folder with everything needed for the demo)
5. Get [the offical demo](https://github.com/PolymerElements/platinum-push-messaging/blob/master/demo/index.html) for `platinum-push-messaging` and the [manifest.json](https://github.com/PolymerElements/platinum-push-messaging/blob/master/demo/manifest.json) (copy those files inside the folder you've just created)
6. In `index.html` change the 6 `rel="imports"` to the corresponding element's `.html` file inside `bower_components` and the webcomponents include to `bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js`. The imports should look somewhat like this:

   ```
   <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html">
   <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-styles/classes/global.html">
   <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
   <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html">
   <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toggle-button/paper-toggle-button.html">
   <link rel="import" href="bower_components/platinum-push-messaging/platinum-push-messaging.html">
   <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
   ```
7. Go to the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com) and create a project.
8. Select "manage all projects", "Settings", select your project and copy the "Project number"
9. Open the `manifest.json` and set `gcm_sender_id` to the copied number.
10. Go back to the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com) and open the "API Manager" (left sidebar), "Credentials"
11. Create a new Credential **Server key** and copy the API **key** (you will need it in a later step so save it in a .txt or something similar)
12. Open "Library" and click "Google Cloud Messaging" and click **Enable** (top of the screen).
13. Run `polymer serve --open`
14. Click on the `paper-toggle-button` to enable push messaging (if the current subscription doesn't show anything, try to disable and reenable it)
15. Copy the `curl` command at the bottom of the `paper-material`
16. Paste the command to your Terminal and replace `[YOUR_PUBLIC_API_KEY]` with the API key you copied in step 11
17. When you run the command, you should receive a push message!

**Note:** If you have problems finding stuff in the Google Developers Console, there is a [great Tutorial](http://dev.tapjoy.com/faq/how-to-find-sender-id-and-api-key-for-gcm/).

[image]

Comment: Awesome!!! this is better than the documentation that it´s in the Polymer site, thanks a lot...